# MySQL Operand should contain 3 column(s)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
let ids = [100,200,300]
let scond_ids = [100,200,300]
let name = ["a","b","c"]

connection.query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (id,second_id,name) in ((?),(?),(?))", [ids,second_ids,name], (err,result,field) => {
    if(err)console.log(err)
});
```

> Operand should contain 3 column(s)

I get this error when I do this with node.js
Please tell me how to fix!!

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen such syntax. I would change to statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id in ? and second_id in ? and name in ?
```

Also if you work with prepared statements you should not add the brackets for in functions.